# What is the Maximum Likelihood Estimator for which coin was tossed?

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

You are given three coins with the following probabilities of observing a Head when tossed:
Coin 1 has a P(H) = 1/2,
Coin 2 has a P(H) = 1/3,
Coin 3 has a P(H) = 1/4.

You observed two heads among three tosses, and you would like to find which coin the observations come from. What is the Maximum Likelihood Estimator for which coin was tossed (Coin 1, 2, or 3)?

I found this question on an online question site and I am confused of what the question is trying to ask.

I know that the possibility of getting 2 heads within 3 tosses is 3/8.

But I am not sure where to go from here. How do I solve this?

Comment: Are all three coins tossed? Or are the observed three tosses done with a randomly selected coin?

Comment: @drhab all three are tossed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand things well now then one of the coins is thrown $3$ times and this resulted in $2$ heads and $1$ tail.

The question we ask ourselves is: which of the $3$ will be used most likely?

If $H$ denotes the number of heads and $C$ denotes the label of the coin then it is not difficult to find:

- $P(H=2\mid C=1)=3\times 2^{-3}$
- $P(H=2\mid C=2)=3\times(1/3)^2(2/3)$
- $P(H=2\mid C=3)=3\times(1/4)^2(3/4)$

That tells us that: $$P\left(H=2\mid C=1\right)=\max\left\{ P\left(H=2\mid C=\eta\right)\mid\eta\in\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} \right\} $$and makes us decide that **most** **likely** it was coin $1$ that was used.

Another expression for $P(H=2\mid C=\eta)$ is $L(C=\eta\mid H=2)$.

Here $P$ represents probability (of some event) and $L$ represents likelihood (of some parameter).

Comment: where did ((2/3)^2) come from in the second equation and (2/4)*2 in the third equation?

Comment: and if I was to find the likelihood of finding two heads among three tosses. Does it mean the answer is P(H) = 3/8?

Comment: There was a typo in second and third equation. That is fixed now. The second equation states that the probability on 2 heads by 3 throws is 3(1/3)^2(2/3) (binomial distribution) if the probability on heads is 1/3.

Comment: I do not really understand the question you posed in your second comment. If you throw a fair coin 3 times then the probability on twice a head is 3/8. Is that what you mean? For that not the term likelihood is used but term probability. It concerns an event. Term likelihood is preserved for parameters (in this context the coin labels).

Comment: thanks for being so helpful. What your answer does is to  find the likelihood of getting two heads among three tosses for each coin. So I was wondering if we can define the likelihood of getting two heads among three tosses (not for each coin). What

Comment: My answer does not find the *likelihood* of getting two heads among three tosses for each coin but find the *probability* of getting two heads among three tosses for each coin. Do you want to know the probability of getting two heads among three tosses if all three coins are used? If so then for that we must first have a probability distribution for the coin labels. In the case where they are equiprobable then the answer is $$P(H=2)=\frac13P(H=2\mid C=1)+\frac13P(H=2\mid C=2)+\frac13P(H=2\mid C=3)$$ Here $P(C=i)=\frac13$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I want to learn how to use the maximum likelihood and the likelihood in this problem. After looking at the two answers I think I get an idea to do that now. I will look for the likelihood of getting two heads among three tosses myself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Considering the Binomial experiment $\mathcal Bin(3,p)$  where two heads among three tosses are observed using one and only one of the three coins with different probabilities $p$, if $\eta$ denotes the unknown label of the coin $(\eta=1,2,3)$, the likelihood of the parameter $\eta$ associated with the available data $\mathcal D$ is
$$L(\eta|\mathcal D)=
\begin{cases}(1/2)(1/2)^{2} & \text{if }\eta=1\\
(2/3)(1/3)^2 & \text{if }\eta=2\\
(3/4)(1/4)^2 & \text{if }\eta=3\\
\end{cases}$$
$-$ where the multiplicative term$^\dagger$ $${3 \choose 2}=3$$ in the Binomial probability$$\mathbb P_p(X=2)={3 \choose 2}p^2(1-p)^1$$ is omitted since it does not depend on the parameter $\eta$ $-$ which corresponds to
$$L(\eta|\mathcal D)=
\begin{cases}0.125 & \text{if }\eta=1\\
0.074 & \text{if }\eta=2\\
0.047 & \text{if }\eta=3\\
\end{cases}$$
The maximum likelihood estimator is thus $\hat\eta=1$, meaning coin #1 is the most likely in producing this outcome.

---

$^\dagger$One should note that the likelihood function is usually defined up to a multiplicative constant.

Comment: can you explain how you got those numbers ?

Comment: It seems that your $L(\eta\mid\mathcal D)$ stands for $P(C=\eta\mid H=2)$ where $C$ denotes the coin label and $H$ the number of heads that are thrown. Is that indeed the intention? If so then you forgot a factor $3$ in all cases. Your answer seems to be that most likely the coin with label $1$ has been thrown (is my interpretation correct?). However in a comment on my comment on the question the OP tells us that all $3$ coins are thrown.

Comment: @drhab Although I had answered your question like that. I reread the question and it seemed like only one of the coin was tossed? That is why it is asking which coin the observations come from.

Comment: @jimmy1998 Then do you understand this answer now? In a certain way I made clear how the Xi'an got those numbers (the forgotten factor $3$ does not play an essential role because we are only interested in the maximum of these numbers).

Comment: Unfortunately I wrote $P(C=\eta\mid H=2)$ in my first comment. What I meant was $P(H=2\mid C=\eta)$. Sorry.

Comment: @drhab Is it possible for you to write the formula of when (=∣=2). I am new to MLE and I don't know where to insert which numbers. I suppose that that is Joint probability distribution?

Comment: @drhab or is it possible to write a more detailed answer in another section? I can vote it as helpful later and ask you there if I have more questions.

Comment: (+1) Things are clear now. Up to some level I am familiar with "probability" but not so much with "likelihood". Statistics is for a large deal beyond my scope.